# Adicionar List(Of String) ao Listbox de um Form

Tags: vb.net

Galera Eu Tenho o seguinte Codigo em minha DLL FTP para obter as pasta do server:

```
Try



            Dim Serv As Net.FtpWebRequest = GetRequest(GetDirectory(directory))



            Serv.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory



            Dim reader As New StreamReader(Serv.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            Dim line = reader.ReadLine()
            Dim lines As New List(Of String)

            Do Until line Is Nothing
                lines.Add(line)
                line = reader.ReadLine()
            Loop


            Return lines.ToArray()
        Catch ex As Exception


        End Try
```

Mas sempre que tento listar os diretorios na list box do formulario aparece o seguinte na LST **System.String[]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para adicionar estas informações no *Listbox* utilize *DataSource*:

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim arquivo As New List(Of String)
        arquivo.Add("file1")
        arquivo.Add("file2")
        arquivo.Add("file3")

        Dim arrArqu = arquivo.ToArray()

        ListBox1.DataSource = arrArqu 'ou simplesmente arquivo
    End Sub
```

Comment: Por questões de aprender melhor, sera que poderia me explica sobre a DataSouce da LST?

Comment: Uma pergunta! Se eu fazer assim n tem como eu saber quantos arquivos serão listado acima o seu codigo lista tres arquivos! fica limitado a ter que programar a quantidade, não é uma coisa dinamica ou eu to errado?? sou novo no VB :D

Comment: De acordo com [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/x8160f6f(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1m) a propriedade `DataSouce` é uma propriedade do `object` que implementa a interface `IList`, então, pode receber como valor Litas ou Arrays. O exemplo acima é apenas para ilustrar, veja que está fazendo a mesma coisa no seu código `Do Until` de forma dinâmica. Para saber a quantidade basta usar a propriedade `Count`.

Comment: Obrigado! Pego Certinho.

Comment: Não esqueça de avaliar a resposta. @VyctorJunior ;)